# Logstash not responding at container image of kibana and logstash

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash, kibana

I am doing a POC at elasticsearch Kibana where I am trying to register my GCS(Google Cloud Storage) for log archiving

For same I am attempting to have a container at `Docker Desktop` of `Elasticsearch` and `Kibana`

For this I am using the below docker compose file

```
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.12.0
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard:   -1
  kibana:
    image: kibana:8.12.0
    ports:
      - '5601:5601'
```

**Issue:**

My logstash is unresponsive at `http://localhost:9200/`. As per documentation I should have received a json response at this URL. Kindly suggest where I could be going wrong

I have got my Kibana up on the exposed port
[image]
But my logstash is not getting up.
[image: Logstash not responding]
It is showing proper metrics though at Docker Desktop
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is misunderstanding the names of some products. I am sharing the details of main Elastic Stack products as follows.

1. **Elasticsearch**: Distributed search and analytics engine. Elasticsearch use port `9200` by default.
2. **Kibana**: Data visualization tool for Elasticsearch. Kibana uses port 5601 by default.
3. **Logstash**: Data processing pipeline for ingesting and transforming diverse data into Elasticsearch and more. Logstash uses port `9600` by default.

From your question I assume that you're talking about elasticsearch that runs port 9200 as default. According to the [image that you shared from kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U00WO.png) it's working fine. [Looks like you are trying to access elasticsearch with port 9200 but without **HTTPS**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rArdG.png) so try like the following. `https://localhost:9200`.

To fix the problem, you can create an enrollment token with the following command and paste the json into kibana, after that elastic will configure itself automatically.

```
docker exec -it es01 /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana
```

once kibana configured you can use the following command to reset elastic password and login.

```
docker exec -it es01 /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic
```

For more information check this article: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Comment: Thanks.. was able to access it at `https://localhost:9200`

Comment: You're welcome, happy to hear it works fine :)